# How to Reverse JQuery Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm very new to JQuery and web dev in general and I need some help. I have been googling this for a couple days now and I can't seem to find a solution that works. I have seen the same question asked on here a lot but many of the answers have been earmarked as outdated in the current release of JQuery.

Basically I have a 'div' that I want to be focused in the middle of the screen when it is clicked. This part works fine. What I can't figure out how to do is have the same 'div' go back to its original position when clicked a 2nd time.

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $("#profile").on ("click", function() {
    $("#profile").animate({right: '15%', height: '+=50px', width: '+=25%'});
    $("#profile").css("position", "absolute"); // So that the div can maintain its normal position in bootstrap grid up until animation
    $("#fadeback").css("opacity", 0.6).fadeIn(300); // Fades everything else on page
  });
});
```

So, I mostly just need a way to 'undo' this set of operations upon a 2nd click. If you have another idea completely separate from my current implementation I'm completely open to it. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: possible for you to create a jsFiddle or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```js
function firstClick() {
    alert('put your animation');
    $(this).one("click", secondClick);
}
function secondClick() {
    alert('put your reverse animation');
    $(this).one("click", firstClick);
}

$("#profile").one("click", firstClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile">
click me
</div>
```

**with your code:**

```
function firstClick() {
   $("#profile").animate({right: '15%', height: '+=50px', width: '+=25%'});
    $("#profile").css("position", "absolute"); // So that the div can maintain its normal position in bootstrap grid up until animation
    $("#fadeback").css("opacity", 0.6).fadeIn(300); // Fades everything else on page
  });
}
function secondClick() {
// reverse your animation
}


$(document).on("page:change", function() {
$("#profile").one("click", firstClick);
});
```

Comment: I'll give it a try after class tonight and report back, thanks!

Comment: I was able to squeeze in the time to do it and it worked great! Thank you! I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep.